# Using git bundle create to backup repos to a specific directory?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, backup

I am working on backing some git repos as part of a new back up plan.  It seems git bundle is the way to go, but I am wondering, and in my, in all honesty, short google searches, I cannot seem to find out if I can do a bundle directly into a specific directory.

For my SVN I mounted a cifs share, and pointed the dump directly to that share without having to script a basic thing to create and then move.

Let me know, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back-uping a git repository is as simple as either:

- `git clone --bare` it to a new place. It allows to `git push/pull` for incremental backup.
- `tar -czf backup.tar.gz myrepo/.git/` file and copy it somewhere. So you can manage it in a simple file, easily.

It's easy.

Comment: The push pull isn't going to work because its for offsite DR, as far as backing up the a singular file, it is looking like I'll be doing a backup of choice and then moving/copying file to my desired location.  Should be easy enough to script and add to cron.